# how many types of events actually exists in the theory of probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I read many article on the internet and found that 
there are only three types of event that can be occurred(or that has been considered in the probability theory).

those are :

mutually exclusive events

independent events

dependent events

Question :

1) Are these only type of events considered in probability theory ?

2) Any ORing or ANDing can be possible between them ?

3) How the formula changes if the ORing and ANDing is possible ?

4) please give the example of them , if possible

Comment: I don't think these are "types of events" in the sense that most people mean "types." For example, "dependent events" refers to multiple events, not the individual events. No single event is "independent" or "dependent" on its own.

Comment: In particular, an event can be "dependent" in one set of events, and "independent" in another set of events, and "mutually exclusive" in a third set. So these terms are not properties of the event...

Comment: This is more a list of relations among events.

Answer (score 1):

You list properties of families of events, not of single events. In the simplest case of two events $A,B$, they are

- mutually exclusive $A\cap B=\emptyset$.
- independent if $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.
- dependent if they are not independent.

By definition, two events cannot be both dependent and independent.
For mutually exclusive events we conclude $P(A\cap B)=0$; hence mutually exclusive events are independent iff one of the events is almost impossible. In any other situation, mutually exclusive events are automatically dependant.